# Dialog not honoring newlines from command output

Tags: bash, dialog

I am writing a script that utilizes `dialog` to interact with users. Part of the functionality is to display information about the host system.

I am implementing this as such:

```bash
    clear;
    echo "Retrieving system information..."

    local ipAddrs="$(hostname -I)"
    local release="$(cat /etc/os-release)"
    local uname="$(uname -a)"
    local hwInfo="$(hwinfo --short)"
    local usbDevs="$(lsusb)"
    local diskUsage="$(df -H)"


    local sysInfo="Ip Address(es): $ipAddrs\n\n$release\n\n$uname\n\nhwinfo:\n$hwInfo\n\nUSB devices:\n$usbDevs\n\nDisk usage:\n$diskUsage"

    echo "Done retrieving system info."

    $DIALOG --title "Host OS Info" --msgbox "$sysInfo" 30 $SUPER_WIDE_WIDTH
```

Which gets displayed as such:

[image: Poorly formatted text]

For normal bash output, I would be doing things fine at this point, as I am sure to quote-wrap all outputs. I'm not sure what to do about a `dialog` context however.  My first thought is perhaps to escape the newlines in the text, but unsure how, as the newlines I have manually specified (unescaped) seem to do fine.

Comment: I can't duplicate; `dialog --msgbox "$(df -H)" 40 80` preserves newlines when I try it, for example.

Comment: Even more odd. I have no words

Comment: I must admit that I have never worked with _dialog_,  but your `sysInfo` does not contain newlines, but character sequences `\n`. Perhaps _dialog_ does not interpret them as newlines. Try to insert real newline characters (i.e. line feed) instead. In the example given by Shawn in his comment, there are newlines in the string passed to `--msgbox`, so this seems to work.

Comment: At this point, I'm assuming that it was the mixed use of escaped/unescaped newlines, and `dialog` just processed assuming they were all escaped, ignoring the unescaped ones

Answer (score 0):

I'll be danged, the escaping of newlines worked. Huh.

Bash is odd

```bash
    local ipAddrs="$(hostname -I)"
    ipAddrs="${ipAddrs//$'\n'/\\n}"
    local release="$(cat /etc/os-release)"
    release="${release//$'\n'/\\n}"
    local uname="$(uname -a)"
    uname="${uname//$'\n'/\\n}"
    local hwInfo="$(hwinfo --short)"
    hwInfo="${hwInfo//$'\n'/\\n}"
    local usbDevs="$(lsusb)"
    usbDevs="${usbDevs//$'\n'/\\n}"
    local diskUsage="$(df -H)"
    diskUsage="${diskUsage//$'\n'/\\n}"
```

[image]