# Preserve line breaks with extra text in a dialog using the 'dialog' command

Tags: bash

I would like to show a dialog with, for example, the following information:

```
dialog --msgbox "set to: $(cat /etc/timezone)\n$(timedatectl)" 20 80
```

My expectation was that this would preserve the line breaks of the command output, but it doesn't seem to.

When I set only the command without extra content, it works as expected:

```
dialog --msgbox "$(timedatectl)" 20 80
```

Is there a way to make "dialog" accept the line breaks?

Comment: See: [Dialog not honoring newlines from command output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72987005/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you cannot mix the escape sequence `\n` with literal newlines in `dialog`, check those examples:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

dialog --msgbox 'AI said:\nhello\nworld' 10 15       # escaped newlines

dialog --msgbox $'AI said:\nhello\nworld' 10 15      # literal newlines

dialog --msgbox 'AI said:\n'$'hello\nworld' 10 15    # escaped + literal newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Fravadona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3387716/fravadona), I was able to get to the following solution

The one that finally worked for me is:

```
#!/bin/bash
new_timezone="$(timedatectl | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g')"
dialog --title "Timezone Updated" --msgbox "Timzone updated to $tmzone\n\n$new_timezone" 20 80
```

The output of timedatectl is piped to the sed command, which performs a substitution on the output. The substitution command :`a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g` does the following:

`:a;N;$!ba;` creates a loop to read the entire output of timedatectl.
`s/\n/\\n/g` replaces any newline characters in the output with the string `\n`, which represents a newline character in a dialog box.